# 8TB Hard Disk mount failed

Tags: mount, gpt, fdisk, parted

**Environment**
  1. OS : Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
  2. HDD : 8TB HDD

**Symptom** : **/dev/sdb1 does not exist.**

root@hprnd:/home/hprnd# **mount /dev/sdb1 /hprnd0004**
mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist

root@hprnd:/home/hprnd# **fdisk -l /dev/sdb**
The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.3 TiB, 8000987201536 bytes, 15626928128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3BC47CA0-6E0B-4157-A5C3-C50A7098DDEB

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
*/dev/sdb1     34 15626928094 15626928061  7.3T Linux filesystem*

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

root@hprnd:/home/hprnd# **parted /dev/sdb**
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p
Error: 부적절한 인수 during seek for read on /dev/sdb
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? c
Model: DELL PERC H730P Adp (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 8001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
(parted) q
root@hprnd:/home/hprnd#

root@hprnd:/home/hprnd# **gdisk -l /dev/sdb**
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v' to
verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to repair
the disk.
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 15626928128 sectors, 7.3 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 3BC47CA0-6E0B-4157-A5C3-C50A7098DDEB
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 15628053134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1125040 sectors (549.3 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              34     15626928094   7.3 TiB     8300  segate8TB05

** How can I mount this disappeared partition on /dev/? **

Comment: *You should use 'v' to verify disk integrity*...

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. Could you let me know what the 'v' mean such as fdisk -v or parted -v?. Thank you for the reply, again.

Comment: Like with any other command you can find information by typing `man gdisk`. Scrolling down you'l  find the meaning for all the arguments. The quote was just a hint though, a hint for checking your drive for errors because it clearly has errors that are described in the error messages,.